# How does one set keypad mode for jed editor with EDT Emulation?

Tags: linux, openvms, edt

How does one switch between command line and keypad modes when using the [`jed`](http://www.jedsoft.org/jed) editor with `EDT` emulation?

[OpenVMS User's Manual](http://h71000.www7.hp.com/doc/73final/6489/6489pro_020.html#edt_ch) states that when using the `EDT` editor if the user wants to control `EDT` using the keypad, the mode needs to be set for keypad rather than command line input:

> To initiate keypad editing, you must
>   first enter the line-editing command
>   CHANGE

I am using:

```
(Jed 0.99.18U) EDT
Linux 2.6.31-19-generic #56-Ubuntu SMP
```

with this `.jedrc` file:

```
evalfile ("edt"); pop ();
unsetkey ("^H"); setkey ("bol", "^H");
```

Using the `-batch` shows that the `.jedrc` file is correctly located.

```
$ jed -batch
loading /usr/share/jed/lib/site.slc
loading /usr/share/jed/lib/os.sl
loading /usr/share/jed/lib/menus.slc
loading /usr/share/jed/lib/defaults.sl
loading /etc/jed.d/05jed-common.sl
loading /etc/jed.d/50jed-extra.sl
loading /usr/share/jed/jed-extra/libdir.slc
loading /usr/share/jed/jed-extra/ini.slc
loading /usr/share/jed/jed-extra/drop-in/ini.slc
loading /etc/jed.d/55jedstate.sl
loading /usr/share/jed/jed-extra/gdbmrecent.slc
loading /usr/share/slsh/local-packages/gdbm.sl
loading /usr/share/jed/jed-extra/utils/sl_utils.slc
loading /home/cwhii/.jedrc
loading /usr/share/jed/lib/edt.slc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `jed` only supports the keypad mode so there is no command to switch to it since it is already in keypad mode. This is documented in the `jed` `EDT` help message.

Invoke `jed` then

```
<esc>HB<downArrow><downArrow><downArrow><downArrow><enter>
```

to display the `EDT` help. Then scroll down to the last line:

> JED does not support any EDT line editing commands, nor are there any plans to do so.